# Why must io_service::reset() be called?

Tags: boost-asio

`io_service::reset` [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html) states that `reset()` must be called before subsequent calls to `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()`.

Questions:

- Why is this necessary?  -
- What behaviour might I expect if this step is neglected?
- Why is this requirement not important enough to warrant an `assert` if it's neglected?

Some context: I finished debugging some unit-tests that checked that called `poll()` repeatedly without `reset()` and was attempting to check the expected number of handlers was being executed each time. It appears that with enough calls to `poll()`, all handlers are eventually executed in the order expected, but it takes more calls than you would otherwise expect. Correctly calling `reset()` fixes the problem, but I'm curious to know if this is the only side effect of not calling `reset()`, or if there are potentially worse effects such as dropping handlers or effects that might appear in a multi-threaded example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the `io_service` has been stopped:

- all invocations of `poll()`, `poll_one()`, `run()`, and `run_one()` will return as soon as possible
- subsequent calls to `poll()`, `poll_one()`, `run()`, and `run_one()` will return immediately without invoking any handlers or processing the event loop

Invoking [`io_service::reset()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html) sets the `io_service` to no longer be in a stopped state, allowing subsequent calls to `poll()`, `poll_one()`, `run()`, and `run_one()` to invoke handlers and process the event loop.

---

> Why is this necessary?

It is necessary if one wishes to invoke handlers or process the event loop once the `io_service` has been stopped explicitly via [`io_service.stop()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/stop.html) or implicitly by running out of work.

> What behaviour might I expect if this step is neglected?

If `io_service.stopped()` is `true`, then subsequent calls to `poll()`, `poll_one()`, `run()`, and `run_one()` will not perform any work.

> Why is this requirement not important enough to warrant an assert if it's neglected?

The [`io_service::reset()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html) documentation's use of the word "must" tends to set an overly critical tone without mentioning the consequences of not calling `reset()`.  The behavior  described by [`io_service::stop()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/stop.html) is not critical enough to warrant an error:

- > Subsequent calls to `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` will return immediately until `reset()` is called.

For `reset()`, the only hard requirement is to not call it when there are unfinished calls to `poll()`, `poll_one()`, `run()`, and `run_one()`.