# async_write_some callback not called after delay

Tags: boost, tcp, callback, boost-asio, asyncsocket

My callback for `async_write_some` is not called after a one second sleep.  If I am starting an `io_service` worker thread for every write, why is the callback not being called?

**header**

```
boost::system::error_code error_1;
boost::shared_ptr <boost::asio::io_service> io_service_1;
boost::shared_ptr <boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_1;
```

**connect**

```
void eth_socket::open_eth_socket (void)
{
    // 1. reset io services
    io_service_1.reset();
    io_service_1 = boost::make_shared <boost::asio::io_service> ();

    // 2. create endpoint
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint remote_endpoint(
        boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("10.0.0.3"), 
        socket_1_port
    );

    // 3. reset socket
    socket_1.reset(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(*io_service_1));                

    // 4. connect socket
    socket_1->async_connect(remote_endpoint,
        boost::bind(
            &eth_socket::socket_1_connect_callback,
            this, boost::asio::placeholders::error
        )
    );

    // 5. start io_service_1 run thread after giving it work
    boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, *&io_service_1));                
    return;
}
```

**write**

```
void eth_socket::write_data (std::string data)
{   
    // 1. check socket status
    if (!socket_1->is_open())
    {
        WARNING << "socket_1 is not open";
        throw -3;
    }

    // 2. start asynchronous write
    socket_1->async_write_some(
        boost::asio::buffer(data.c_str(), data.size()),
        boost::bind(
            &eth_socket::socket_1_write_data_callback,
            this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, 
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
        )
    );

    // 3. start io_service_1 run thread after giving it work
    boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, *&io_service_1));
    return;
}
```

**callback**

```
void eth_socket::socket_1_write_data_callback (const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    // 1. check for errors
    if (error) 
    {
        ERROR << "error.message() >> " << error.message().c_str();
        return;
    }
    if (socket_1.get() == NULL || !socket_1->is_open())
    {
        WARNING << "serial_port_1 is not open";
        return;
    }
    INFO << "data written to 10.0.0.3:1337 succeeded; bytes_transferred = " << bytes_transferred;
    return;
}
```

**test**

```
open_eth_socket();
write_data("Hello");    // callback called
write_data("Hello");    // callback called
write_data("Hello");    // callback called
sleep(1);
write_data("Hello");    // callback not called after sleep
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, *&io_service_1));
```

That's weird for a number of reasons.

- You should not "run" io_services for each operation. Instead, run them steadily while operations may be posted. Optionally use `io_service::work` to prevent run from returning.
- You should not (have to) create threads for each operation. If anything, it's recipe for synchronization issues ([Why do I need strand per connection when using boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042))
- When running `io_service` again after it returned (without error) you should call `reset()` first, as per documentation ([Why must io_service::reset() be called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643311/why-must-io-servicereset-be-called))
- You destruct a non-detached thread - likely before it had completed. If you had used `std::thread` this would even have caused immediate abnormal program termination. It's bad practice to not-join non-detached threads (and I'd add it's iffy to use detached threads without explicit synchronization on thread termination). See [Why is destructor of boost::thread detaching joinable thread instead of calling terminate() as standard suggests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874493/why-is-destructor-of-boostthread-detaching-joinable-thread-instead-of-calling)

I'd add to these top-level concerns

- the smell from using names like `socket_1` (just call it `socket_` and instantiate another object with a descriptive name to contain the other `socket_`). I'm not sure, but the question does raise suspicion these might even be global variables. (I hope that's not the case)
- `throw`-ing raw integers, really?
- You are risking full on data-races by destructing `io_service` while never checking that worker threads had completed.
- More [**Undefined Behaviour**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) here:

  ```
  _sock.async_write_some(
          ba::buffer(data.c_str(), data.size()),
  ```

  You pass a reference to the parameter `data` which goes out of scope. When the async operation completes, it will be a dangling reference
- There's some obvious copy/paste trouble going on here:

  ```
  if (socket_1.get() == NULL || !socket_1->is_open())
  {
      WARNING << "serial_port_1 is not open";
      return;
  }
  ```

  I'd actually say this stems from precisely the same source that lead to the variable names being `serial_port_1` and `socket_1`

#### Some Cleanup

Simplify. There wasn't self-contained code, so nothing complete here, but at least see the many points of simplification:

[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8cbef32c68252328)

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace ba = boost::asio;
using ba::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

#define ERROR   std::cerr
#define WARNING std::cerr
#define INFO    std::cerr

struct eth_socket {

    ~eth_socket() {
        _work.reset();
        if (_worker.joinable())
            _worker.join(); // wait
    }

    void open(std::string address);
    void write_data(std::string data);

  private:
    void connected(error_code error) {
        if (error)
            ERROR << "Connect failed: " << error << "\n";
        else
            INFO << "Connected to " << _sock.remote_endpoint() << "\n";
    }
    void written(error_code error, size_t bytes_transferred);

  private:
    ba::io_service _svc;
    boost::optional<ba::io_service::work> _work{ _svc };
    boost::thread _worker{ [this] { _svc.run(); } };

    std::string _data;

    unsigned short _port = 6767;
    tcp::socket _sock{ _svc };
};

void eth_socket::open(std::string address) {
    tcp::endpoint remote_endpoint(ba::ip::address::from_string(address), _port);

    _sock.async_connect(remote_endpoint, boost::bind(&eth_socket::connected, this, _1));
}

void eth_socket::write_data(std::string data) {
    _data = data;

    _sock.async_write_some(ba::buffer(_data), boost::bind(&eth_socket::written, this, _1, _2));
}

void eth_socket::written(error_code error, size_t bytes_transferred) {
    INFO << "data written to " << _sock.remote_endpoint() << " " << error.message() << ";"
         << "bytes_transferred = " << bytes_transferred << "\n";
}

int main() {
    {
        eth_socket s;
        s.open("127.0.0.1");

        s.write_data("Hello"); // callback called
        s.write_data("Hello"); // callback called
        s.write_data("Hello"); // callback called
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
        s.write_data("Hello"); // callback not called after sleep

    } // orderly worker thread join here
}
```

Comment: Note this leaves the problem with data-race when `write_data` overlaps a prior read. I'll link to the common solution for that later.

Comment: Thank you.  I figured my problem was with the `io_service` and thread.  So the `_work` thread is always running?  In the callback I should have `io_service_1->reset();` and start the `io_service` work thread after I connect?  I thought the work thread runs out of work on the callback, therefore I need to start it for each write.

Comment: ... Please just read the sample code/ I didn't write up the sample for no reason. Extra background link perhaps in case you missed it: [Why do we need to use `boos::asio::io_service::work`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156541/why-do-we-need-to-use-boostasioio-servicework) (it refers to the very first bullet, though)

Comment: Oh. I didn't see this before, but `*&io_service_1` is definitely wrong. It's a tautology. You may have (uselessly) meant `&*io_service_`. But `boost::bind` supports `shared_ptr<>` just fine, directly — making it a hell of a lot more safe too)

Answer (score 0):

My problems are now fixed thanks to sehe's help and prayer.

This line in `open_eth_socket`:

```
boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, *&io_service_1));
```

is now this:

```
boost::shared_ptr <boost::thread>  io_service_1_thread;    // in header

if (io_service_1_thread.get()) io_service_1_thread->interrupt();
io_service_1_thread.reset(new boost::thread (boost::bind(&eth_socket::run_io_service_1, this)));
```

I added this function:

```
void eth_socket::run_io_service_1 (void)
{
  while (true)  // work forever
  {
    boost::asio::io_service::work work(*io_service_1);
    io_service_1->run();
    io_service_1->reset();   // not sure if this will cause problems yet
    INFO << "io_service_1 run complete";
    boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::milliseconds (100));
  }

    return;
}
```